# How to switch on and off @Recover method in Spring Retry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I want the `@Recover` method to be switched on/off based on a flag in the properties file. How to do that?

Actually, I am not using annotations (`@Retryable` / `@Recover`), instead, I am using `RetryTemplate`.

**Solution**

I am using this following method as a wrapper method to all the recover calls.

```
private <T> T genericRecover(RetryContext context) {
    if(this.useRecoverMethod) {
        return null;
    }

    throw new RuntimeException(context.getLastThrowable());
}
```

Here the `useRecoverMethod` boolean flag is read from the properties file.

```
public Resource<Camera> myRetyableMethod(Long cameraId) {

    return retryTemplate.execute(context -> anApiCallMethod(param),
                                    context -> genericRecover(context));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible.

But, of course, your `@Recover` method can re-throw the exception (or not) based on the property.

Comment: That exactly what I have done. I will update the question with the solution, thx!

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution. Please let me know if I can do anything else to improve up my approach.

Comment: Looks ok except your recoverer does nothing except ignore the error. Perhaps that's what you want but, generally, people want to do something else, or at least log the problem.